# How to read the man pages in german?

Tags: command-line, man, locale

on my Ubuntu 16.04,

- the **de** folder inside **/usr/share/man** is present
- `locale -a` shows de_DE.utf8 is available

So, if I have both, the man pages in german and german locales available, why do I still get man pages in english, when I type:

```
LANG=de_DE.utf8 man grep
```

Comment: Is `$LC_MESSAGES` overridden somewhere else? What is the output of `locale` (no `-a`) under your `LANG=de_DE.utf8` setting?

Comment:  locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: LC_MESSAGES is empty

Comment: German man pages https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=german+man+pages ... The first eight hits are about German man pages.